# Pointer arguments in void function returning inconsistent values

Tags: c++, pointers

This might be a stupid simple thing I'm overlooking, but I am setting values in the `Data::Data(char *DataType...)` function as they are being passed in, and as I hover over them, they are setting fine (the variables `type, material, ID, unit, reading` when hovered over are what they should be).

However, when the `getData` function is called below, when I hover over the pointer arguments(`*type, *materials.. etc`) they are set to random strings like directory names and file names. I'm not sure why this is happening, because when the variables are being set above they are right.

I've included the header and implementation files for the Data class, where all of these functions are defined, but If I need include where they are being called please let me know, the only reason I didn't is because the calls are short and files are filled with other irrelevant stuff. Thanks

```
Data.cpp
#include "Data.hpp"

Sensor::Sensor(char *DataType, char *Material, int ID, char *Sensor, double Min, double Max) {
  strcpy(type, Type);
  strcpy(material, Material);
  ID = SIDs;
  strcpy(unit, Units);
  max = Maxs;
  min = Mins;
}
Sensor::Sensor() {}


double Data::generateData() {
  reading = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
  return reading;
}

void Data::getData(char *type, char *material, int *ID, char *unit, double *reading) {
  return;
}

Data::~Data(){}
```

Data.hpp

```
#ifndef Data_hpp
#define Data_hpp

#include
#include
#include

using namespace std;

class Data
{
public:
  Data();
  Data(char *Type, char *Material, int ID, char *Unit, double Min, double Max);
  ~Data();


  void getData(char *type, char *material, int *ID, char *unit, double *reading);

private:
  char type[32];
  char material[32];
  int ID;
  int reading;
  char unit[32];
  double min;
  double max;
  double generateData();
};
#endif
```

Comment: Please add a snippet where `getSensorData` is being invoked and its arguments are set.

Comment: You should indent your code.

Comment: Also please remove commented code from your example as it presumably has no effect on the situation in question.

Comment: @meat done, check it out

Comment: @MaxLanghof done check it out

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Is that `return` actually the full code of `getSensorData`? You should know that the e.g. `char* type` parameter in there is unrelated to the member `char type[32];` - one hides the other.

Comment: yes it is, i wanted to return a bunch of variables of different types and i read the way to do that was to create a void function and make the variables i want to pass pointers. so should i set char *type like this->type to  fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem as you can see [here](http://cpp.sh/56j2q). You need to provide more information or create a [mcve] containing the problem.

Comment: Giving parameters to a function that is a member of a class names that match the names of data members of that same class is a terrible idea. I suggest renaming class data members to names that have an underscore at the end, like `type_`, `material_`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `Sensor::getData` does not do what you think it does.

Let's look at this class:

```
class Foo
{
  void getX(int* x)
  {
  }

  int* x;
};
```

Within `getX`, the *parameter* `x` **hides** the *member* `x` of the same name. This function does literally nothing: A user passes a pointer to an `int`, which gets the name `x` in this function. The member is not automatically copied into there (which would be surprising, since you could name the parameter anything else). If you want to do that, you must do it explicitly:

```
void getX(int* x)
{
  *x = *this->x; // Pointed-to value is copied
  //x = this->x; // Pointer is copied
}
```

If you do not set the function parameter to anything, the pointer will keep pointing to random garbage in memory, which is what you are seeing in your debugger.

---

The more common way to denote *"this parameter will be changed/set by this function"* is passing a reference:

```
class Foo
{
  void get(char*& x, int*& y, double& z)
  {
    x = this->x; // Now both parameter and member point to the same location.
    y = this->y; // Now both parameter and member point to the same location.
    z = this->z;
  }

  char x[32];
  int* y;
  double z;
};
```

Or, if you don't want to copy the *pointers* but the *pointed-to values*:

```
  void get(char* x, int* y, double& z)
  {
    strcopy(x, this->x);
    *y = *this->y;
    z = this->z;
  }
```

(PS: I recommend using `std::string` instead of char arrays if your use case allows for it.)

Comment: the last implementation worked for my chars, but my double and int are returning as addresses still . i took the pointer before `this` but still the same.

Comment: There is no way using the `z` way would do anything with adresses. All your non-pointer (i.e. non-string) values should follow the `z` example. If you were to use `std::string` instead of `char[]` you wouldn't have to touch a single pointer (other than `this`).

Answer (score 0):

You uninitialized arguments are set to random garbage no matter if you call `getData()` or not. Try to print them out without calling `getData()` and see.

Comment: where should i print them out? how are they uninitialized if I just initialized them in the constructor?